# elixir - Ecto changeset success and failure code no longer running

Tags: elixir, ecto

This code used to add strings to the messages variable and then send them back in the http response. Now nothing gets added to the messages variable. The lines of code inside the :ok and :error blocks no longer runs. Where should I be dealing with the error and success case now, to add the messages on error and on success?

```
  messages = {}

  changeset = Api.UserProduct.changeset(
    user_product, %{:voted_vegan => true}
  )

  case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, product} -> 
        IO.puts("appending messages7")
        messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
      {:error, changeset} -> 
        IO.puts("appending messages8")
        messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
  end

  conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
      |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{
          successs: "success",
          errors: Tuple.to_list(messages)
      }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case expression has not side effect, you should assign the returned value of the case expression (which will be the value of the last expression in the executed branch) to `messages` variable.

```
messages = {}

changeset =
  Api.UserProduct.changeset(
    user_product,
    %{:voted_vegan => true}
  )

messages =
  case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
    {:ok, product} ->
      IO.puts("appending messages7")
      Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")

    {:error, changeset} ->
      IO.puts("appending messages8")
      Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
  end

conn
|> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
|> send_resp(
  200,
  Poison.encode!(%{
    successs: "success",
    errors: Tuple.to_list(messages)
  })
)
```

Comment: I have about 3 more case statements afterwards which are not in the question. So this solution does not append the messages. It overwrites them. So the last case is all that is in the messages variable. What would be the best way to append to messages with each case statement rather than overwrite it?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins I don't understand your question. Do you need something like this? http://ix.io/1D3w let me know so I add it to the answer

Comment: Yes but I need a more versatile solution. I have deeply nested areas of code where I was appending to `messages`. Your solution is not working there. Elixir language updated and now scope doesn't work the same. At the bottom of the function, `messages` equals `{}` when it has more values whilst in the middle of the function. They must be different scope levels. I just want to append to `messages` from all scope levels, like a global scope. Nightmare.